# react register simultaneous setState (hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that is supposed to listen for multiple key-down events.

```
 const [activeKeys, setActiveKeys] = useState([]);

  const onKeyDown = e => {
    if (!activeKeys.includes(e.key)) {
      console.log("keydown", e.key);
      setActiveKeys([...activeKeys, e.key]);
    }
  };
  const onKeyUp = e => {
    console.log("keyup", e.key);
    setActiveKeys([...activeKeys].filter(i => i !== e.key));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
    };
  });
```

is at the core. the entire code can be found [here (codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/p570m6nmx7)

it works fine 90% of the time, however:

**when 2 keys are released at the exact same time the state doesn't get updated twice.**

(You can try to reproduce it in the codesandbox provided above, press any 2 keys simultaneously and then release them at the exact same time. Might take a few tries to get right, [here is a gif of the issue happening](https://i.gyazo.com/c19077fc79b9b513d3cba3aa8cc6a2ca.gif) and here's what it looks like (the number is the amount of keys pressed down, and the 's' is the key that's supposedly pressed down, however, you can see that that in the console log the keyup of 's' was registered.)
[image: screenshot of bug]

Has anyone encountered something similar before? 
From what I can see the issue is not with

- the event listener (console.log gets fired)
- a rerender (you can try to press some other keys, the key will stay in the array)

that's why I'm assuming that the issue lies with the hook, however I have no way to explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the simple form of `setState(newValue)` and that replaces your state with your new value. You have to use the functional form of `setState( (prevState) => {} );` because your new state depends on the previous state.

Try this:

```
const onKeyDown = e => {
    if (!activeKeys.includes(e.key)) {
      console.log("keydown", e.key, activeKeys);
      setActiveKeys(prevActiveKeys => [...prevActiveKeys, e.key]);
    }
  };
  const onKeyUp = e => {
    console.log("keyup", e.key, activeKeys);
    setActiveKeys(prevActiveKeys =>
      [...prevActiveKeys].filter(i => i !== e.key)
    );
  };
```

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9l60137xjp)

Comment: oh! totally overlooked that in the docs. Do you know if there is a performance difference if I use these callbacks vs useLayoutEffect?

Comment: Not sure. But from my experience, if you're not doing anything that might render tens of thousands of nodes in React, you won't be getting performance issues. Go with what makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I just needed to replace `useEffect` by `useLayoutEffect`

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect):

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your codes and found it is more than just 2 keys, actually you can reproduce it more easily with more keys; try to press asdjkl (6 keys) at the same time and you can see even more mess.

And I think the problem is that, react's rerender cycle is not working with dom event listener, which means `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` fires whenever it wants, but react does not rerender for every triggering of them. Just log `[...activeKeys, e.key]` and `[...activeKeys].filter(i => i !== e.key)` and you will see it.

I think the solution is to use a simple local variable to update the `activeKeys`, then `render` method should use this variable instead of the result of the hook, and finally do a forceUpdate in every `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` to make react rerender.

Comment: creating a variable with useRef(), mutating it and forcing an update does indeed work, (https://codesandbox.io/s/m7n9l18248 if interested) 
however i found that useLayoutEffect is a much better fix

Comment: @cubefox your solution and cbdev420's solution are indeed the better ones, I've learned from yours ;)